# How to detect the use of a particular item in Minecraft Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to make a thirst command block setup, but I can't find how to detect use of an item. I've tried /testfor, but the closest I got was:

```
/testfor @a[hasitem={item=potion,location=slot.weapon.mainhand}]
```

I can't seem to find anything online about it, either.

Comment: Hi Aiden, have you gone through the [list with similar questions here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bminecraft-bedrock-edition%5D+testfor)? I'm sure you can find something to help you along.

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't find anyone in my situation or an answer.